# Automatically start Bash script when opening a graphical program

Tags: gnome, bash, libreoffice

I want to start a shell script automatically when I'm starting, e.g., LibreOffice.

The problem is that I don't know how. Where would I build the trigger to start the script in.

Is there a folder/file where I can build the trigger in?

It would be great if I wouldn't have to build a complete 'new' version of LibreOffice to run a few lines of shell-script.

Comment: Turn your requirements around: write a bash script that does what you need *then* the script launches LibreOffice.

Comment: I don't want to start the programm non-graphical, that's the problem. The other way round would be easy.

Comment: This has already been answered, but I agree with @glennjackman. The accepted answer constantly polls to check if something is running. I can see a few problems with that. Instead, do as glenn suggests, then create a `.desktop` file so you can launch it from a GUI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the easiest way to do what you want.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Define the program to waitfor.
program_to_watch=soffice.bin

my_commands() {
echo "This is where your first command goes."
echo "This is where your second command goes."
}

clear
echo "waitfor program script"
echo "Author: Kris Beazley"
echo "Apache 2.0 License"
echo ""
echo "$(date): Waiting for $program_to_watch to start."

while true
 do
  sleep 1
  if [[ $(ps -A | grep $program_to_watch) && -z $var ]]
    then
    var=true
    echo "$(date): $program_to_watch started."
    echo "$(date): Asking \"my_commands\" to start, and going back to sleep."
    echo "$(date): $(my_commands)"
  fi
  if [[ ! $(ps -A | grep $program_to_watch) && -n $var ]]
    then
    unset var
    echo "$(date): $program_to_watch closed."
    echo "$(date): Going back to sleep."
  fi
 done
```

Just copy this to a text file and set to an executable, but make sure line **#!/usr/bin/env bash** has no blank lines in front of it.

To set executable type:

```
chmod +x myscript.sh
```

Comment: Wow, works great! Sorry that I can't vote you up.

Comment: one littele problem: your code works... but my code not! There is no interpreter in '/bin/env  bash'

Comment: You can use #!/bin/bash   or whereever the bash binary is located just point to it.  I'm surprised #!/bin/env bash did not work.

Comment: @Kris It should be `/usr/bin/env`, not `/bin/env`. (I've edited the answer.)

Comment: @Sparhawk: '/usr/bin/env' isn't working, too. The programm starts, but it isn't doing anything and I can't kill it with 'ctrl c'

Comment: @Kris: '#!/bin/bash' isn't working, too. without any '#!/...' it's working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's very strange. I'm not sure what to make of that. Anyway, as long as it works…